# How I get real size image when I use RenderTargetBitmap or Capture UI

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to get real size image when I use RenderTargetBitmap or Capture UI because When I RenderTargetBitmap or Capture UI. Image is blur and don't clear but when I expand Image to original size image don't blur and clear.

```
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(ImageAndSticker,2500,3750);
            StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.CreateFileAsync("snapshot" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy h.mm.ss.fff tt") + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            storageFile = file;
            var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
            var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
            var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, displayInformation.RawDpiX, displayInformation.RawDpiY, pixels);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
```

```
           <Viewbox Margin="254.8,8,659,474" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both"  x:Name="ViewImage" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0">
           <Image x:Name="frameimage" Margin="176.8,2,459,135" Grid.Column="1" Height="3750" Width="2500" Canvas.Left="-458" Canvas.Top="-641"/> 
           </Viewbox>
```

[image]

Comment: If you have stored the `RenderTargetBitmap`  to the file, you could use [`ImageProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.imageproperties)  to get image property that contain the actual width and height info.

Comment: Can you show example code?

Comment: Please check the above line, and it contains example code.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
frameimage.Source.Width
```

to get source image's width

samething do with Height will get source image's Height value like this

```
frameImage.Source.Height
```

I think you wish to save Source image as file.

if then, use this code.

```
BitmapSource source = frameImage.Source as BitmapSource;

using ( var FileStream = new FileStream( FileLoc, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite) ) {
    BitmapEncoder Encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    Encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
    Encoder.Save(FileStream);
    FileStream.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I try your code is error. I don't know how to solve your code.